# Create Disqus account via api

Tags: disqus

I'm working on a multi-tenanted cms. Each client on the cms can create a blog, and disqus will be used for commenting on blog posts. I would like to allow clients to create their disqus accounts from the cms, and not have to actually go to disqus.com to do it. I'm brand new to disqus and I'm just wondering if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't exactly possible using the API (you can [create a forum](https://disqus.com/api/docs/forums/create/), but not an account), but you can open a direct link to the forum registration page here: https://disqus.com/admin/signup/

This flow isn't as seamless as what you propose, but it does offer the advantage of introducing the user to Disqus. This way they can get acclimated to the moderation tools and settings that they wouldn't see otherwise.